# Regex - Match everything after & including last occurance of \t

Tags: javascript, regex

With regex, how can I match everything after and including the last occurence of an empty space/tab?

For example, `1283128318231283128213 123881213 81328 ajdh suu` should match `suu`

Thanks, this is for JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

`\s[^\s]+$`

Follow link below to see it in action with the test data you provided in your question.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hd5_Igr-gBaO5sP5)

Answer (score 0):

Use `\s` to match a tab or a white-space character. Since your input won't contain any newline character, you may free to use the below regex.

```
> "1283128318231283128213 123881213 81328 ajdh suu".match(/\s\S*$/)[0]
' suu'
```

**Update:**

```
> "PRICE $153.00 $133.05 ".match(/\s\S*/)[0].replace(/\D/g, "")
'15300'
```

Comment: That seems to work for the string I originally posted, but for some reason it isn't working in this context (using jQuery) `var url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Flip%20Knife%20%7C%20Doppler%20%28Factory%20New%29/render?start=0&count=1&currency=1&language=english&format=json';
$.get(url+'?_'+$.now()).done(function(f) { console.log($(f.results_html).find('.market_listing_their_price').text().replace(/\n/g, "").replace(/\s\S*$/g, "$REP")) });`

Comment: I didn't find any space in your input.

Comment: replace(/\t/g, "") makes the output `PRICE$153.00$133.05` versus `PRICE                  $153.00             $133.05  `

Comment: then how come you get the last part if you replace the tab with empty string? You may try `[ \t]\S*$` after replacing the newline charcater.

Comment: I just want the code I posted in this comment to return the first price (15300), how can I do that?? I was planning on stripping the second price then stripping nonalphanumeric characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var re = /^(.*)( |\t)(.*)$/;
var str = "foo bar";
var newstr= str.replace(re, "$3");
console.log(newstr);

var strTwo= "foo    bar";
var newstrTwo = strTwo.replace(re, "$3");
console.log(newstrTwo);
```