# awk regex last occurence of character/pattern

Tags: regex, awk

I need to get the index of the last occurrence of a pattern. Tried ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273177/matching-last-occurance-of-character-using-regex) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147271/regex-match-everything-after-including-last-occurance-of-t). The below does not work if I want the index of the last `:` (index is 6). Tried to use the anchor `$` but clearly have not grasped it (since it gives me the first occurrence, i.e. 3). Explanations really appreciated.

```
echo 12:45:78 | 
awk '
{
print match($1, /:.+$/)
}'
```

Comment: Use `/:[^:]*$/` (`[^:]*` will match 0+ chars other than `:`)

Comment: Actually, [this idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147271/regex-match-everything-after-including-last-occurance-of-t) fits your scenario. How did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I see that now - already looked to that. Getting wiser...

Comment: So `:[^:]` says a `:` and then any character except `:` any number of times ?

Comment: Yes. Do not forget the $ anchor. Also, please check anubhava's answer that might be more optimal for you (unless you need more things to check in your input that would really require a regex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
/:[^:]*$/
```

Here, `[^:]*` (a `[^...]` is a *negated bracket expression*) will match 0+ chars *other than* `:`, so, only the last `:` is matched with the first `:`.

Note [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147271/regex-match-everything-after-including-last-occurance-of-t) is almost right for you, the only difference being the quantifier: if you use `+` with `[^:]`, you won't match the `:` that is at the very end of the input string. Thus, `*` is the quantifier you want.

**Pattern details**:

- `:` - a `:` followed with...
- `[^:]*` - any 0+ chars other than `:`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use any regex here as awk allows you split file using a delimiter.

After using `:` as input field separator subtract last field's length from total line length to get right index like this:

```
awk -F: '{print length($0) - length($NF)}' <<< '12:45:78'

6
```

More examples:

```
awk -F: '{print length($0) - length($NF)}' <<< '12:45:78111:123'
12

awk -F: '{print length($0) - length($NF)}' <<< '12:45:78:123'
9

awk -F: '{print length($0) - length($NF)}' <<< '12:45'
3

awk -F: '{print length($0) - length($NF)}' <<< '12:'
3
```

Comment: When you're using awk better to take advantage of all the awk goodies :)